# Champion Furnace Fault Codes

Tags: hvac

I noticed my Champion furnace short cycling and was told over the summer that this might be a safety overheat condition.

This evening I checked it again and saw a red light flashing 4 times when the burner cuts out.  The user manual says this is a fault code but doesn't list the different codes.  So what's a red "4" and how am I supposed to interpret that?

Comment: have you contacted Champion technical support?

Comment: I only got as far as checking their website.  I will try calling tomorrow.

Comment: I take it there's no labeling on the furnace itself that explains the fault codes either?

Comment: Whether you're asking here or at Champion's tech support, you'll want to know the _exact_ model number.

Comment: "We're unavailable to take your call."

Comment: Sometimes the access panel will have troubleshooting info on the inside.  There is no standard.  Some units might have 4 flashes for a bad flame sensor, and others might have 4 flashes because of an air restriction/pressure error (clogged filter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Furnace locked out about 90 minutes after the thermostat called for 2 more degrees this morning.  Same red 4 code after lockout as with the short cycles.  I took the opportunity to open the door to the gas section, and that's where the codes are listed.

[image]

Next step is to get a contractor out here.  It's a TM8Y model in case that helps anyone later.

Thanks everyone for the comments and encouragement.

Comment: Make sure your filter isn't too restrictive.  Maybe try to run the unit without a filter just to see if it comes on (cover might need to be replaced before trying).   Also look for collapsed ducts or blocked return air vents.   There are also pressure sensors that can go bad, but that might be getting out of your comfort level.

Comment: Good ideas but all beyond my comfort zone.  Needs pro troubleshooting at this point.

Comment: Comfort, schmomfort. You've come this far, why not continue? I've replaced motors, control boards, flame sensors, induction fans, and other parts on my furnaces. Ain't dead yet. As long as you're not intentionally jumping over safety hardware there's fairly little risk to replacing basic components. It's when you get into the heat exchanger and gas controls that it gets sketchier.